# Background image scroll in responsive

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, responsive-images

I integrated a body image, so far so good. But when I go to mobile view and scroll my page, the image of the body goes up. Shows a white margin at the bottom of the screen for about 1 second and finally load all over the screen. But the phenomenon occurs every time I go back and down my page.

Does anyone have a solution or can explain to me why this is happening?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us your code, please? Without, it's very hard to tell why this happens.

Comment: I have no idea. You need to show a [mcve] if you want to get a real answer and not a guess

Answer (score 0):

Add this on top of your CSS file:

```
html,body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow-x: hidden;}
```

It works for me :)